# Bat file not running (Comparison script)

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I am trying to integrate my bat file into a VBScript but first must get it to work independently. If I copy and paste each line, it works fine, but if I put it in a bat file, it just blinks open and closed. I think it was to be the first line, as even if I put a pause after line one, it closes before it gets to pause. So 2 questions:

What am I doing wrong to make this auto close before running? 
Is there a way to make this work in a VBScript?

```
for /r X:\ %i in (*) do @echo %~ni >> C:\Users\Media\Documents\xtemp.txt
sort <C:\Users\Media\Documents\xtemp.txt> C:\Users\Media\Documents\x.txt
del C:\Users\Media\Documents\xtemp.txt

for /r Z:\ %i in (*) do @echo %~ni >> C:\Users\Media\Documents\ztemp.txt
sort <C:\Users\Media\Documents\ztemp.txt> C:\Users\Media\Documents\z.txt
del C:\Users\Media\Documents\ztemp.txt
```

I will then feed this into a comparison script to see if I have the same name for files in each folder and what I may be missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a BAT file you have to double the `%`

```
for /r X:\ %%i in (*) do @echo %%~ni >> C:\Users\Media\Documents\xtemp.txt
sort <C:\Users\Media\Documents\xtemp.txt> C:\Users\Media\Documents\x.txt
del C:\Users\Media\Documents\xtemp.txt

for /r Z:\ %%i in (*) do @echo %%~ni >> C:\Users\Media\Documents\ztemp.txt
sort <C:\Users\Media\Documents\ztemp.txt> C:\Users\Media\Documents\z.txt
del C:\Users\Media\Documents\ztemp.txt
```

Comment: Pipes (|) were invented to supply the output of one command to another's command input: `for /r X:\ %%i in (*) do @echo %%~ni | sort >C:\Users\Media\Documents\x.txt`. Besides, you could use `%%~nxi` to include the extension with the filename to make it unambiguous (bla.txt vs. bla.cmd...).